# What is the method to add new column in existing dataframe in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have added a new column to an existing datframe but it's not reflected in dataframe.

```
customerDf.withColumn("fullname",expr("concat(firstname,'|',lastname)"))

customerDf.show() # it's showing existing old df records without new columns.
```

we can see the results if we can assign the dataframe to another dataframe

```
test = customerDf.withColumn("fullname",expr("concat(firstname,'|',lastname)"))
test.show()
```

Is there any way to add a new column to an existing dataframe (without copy dataframe)?
We will have one option (`inplace=True` in pandas). Do we have any similar function in pyspark?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: **no there is no such thing in pyspark.**

Spark DataFrames are immutable. This means, when you add a new column (or any other transformation) you're not changing the data frame, but creating a new one.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.withColumn:

> Returns a new DataFrame by adding a column or replacing the existing
> column that has the same name.

In Python you can, however, re-assign the result to "same variable" :

```
customerDf = customerDf.withColumn("fullname",expr("concat(firstname,'|',lastname)"))
```